# Can I use my ipad charger bought in Japan in Los Angeles?

Tags: power

Can I use my ipad charger bought in Japan in Los Angeles? Or Do I need any kind of converter?

Comment: What voltages does it say on the label it operates on?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, you (almost certainly) can.  Japan uses the same plugs as the US and a very similar voltage (100 vs 120V) which is within the tolerance range of most any small electronic device.  Check the back of the adapter, which should have an input specification, to confirm.